# iMovie crashes on first startup

Tags: macos, mojave, crash, startup, imovie

I have just downloaded iMovie on my new Mac (I had it on the old one) and it is not able to open. I crashes as soon as I click. I have also tried to restart, to login with the guest account and to delete preferences holding the option.
This is the log:

```
Process:               iMovie [6036]
Path:                  /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie
Identifier:            com.apple.iMovieApp
Version:               10.1.11 (342230)
Build Info:            iMovieX-34223000026000000~1
App Item ID:           408981434
App External ID:       830553401
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           iMovie [6036]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-05-31 11:16:13.914 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.3 (18D109)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        FEEE32BA-8987-DC30-0566-68E4E8A8BDE9

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7E96D044-E8C5-4D6C-90E9-65B7216ACF4E

Time Awake Since Boot: 15000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
/Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ProGraphics.framework/Versions/A/ProGraphics
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff63fa723e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6405dc1c pthread_kill + 285
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff63f101c9 abort + 127
3   com.apple.procore.framework     0x000000010ec12511 pcAbortImpl + 9
4   com.apple.ProGraphics           0x000000011bddb15a (anonymous namespace)::PGInfoImpl::instance() + 730
5   dyld                            0x0000000115b59cc8 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 518
6   dyld                            0x0000000115b59ec6 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
7   dyld                            0x0000000115b550da ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 358
8   dyld                            0x0000000115b5506d ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
9   dyld                            0x0000000115b5506d ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 249
10  dyld                            0x0000000115b54254 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 134
11  dyld                            0x0000000115b542e8 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 74
12  dyld                            0x0000000115b46d20 dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 82
13  dyld                            0x0000000115b5075f dlopen_internal + 609
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff63e5362f dlopen + 200
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff36c3beae _CFBundleDlfcnLoadBundle + 148
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff36cdbca3 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 519
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff390080a0 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 481
18  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010f0a3652 +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner _scanDirectory:withExtension:scanned:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 930
19  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010f0a3b2b +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner scanForPluginsInDirectory:withExtension:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 1067
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62d9c248 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62d8c00c _class_initialize + 282
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62d8bf42 _class_initialize + 80
23  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62d8ba19 lookUpImpOrForward + 238
24  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62d8b494 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
25  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff390084a9 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 1514
26  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010f0a3652 +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner _scanDirectory:withExtension:scanned:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 930
27  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010f0a3b2b +[FFPluginDirectoryScanner scanForPluginsInDirectory:withExtension:delegate:didLoadSelector:] + 1067
28  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010edfad2a +[FFEffect(RuntimeBundleLoading) initEffectRegistry] + 218
29  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010ee2522f FFInitializePart2 + 111
30  com.apple.Flexo                 0x000000010edc73b6 +[Flexo finishInit] + 22
31  com.apple.iMovieApp             0x000000010e96dbb9 main + 1033
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff63e67ed9 start + 1
```

[Full log here](https://pastebin.com/yPjLgdx8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up your machine, and try this: https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/imovie-crashes-on-startup-mojave.267438/

Basically, delete the Prographics Framework. If it works, no need to restore, if it does something even nastier, restore and look elsewhere :)

Comment: "Deleting the ProGraphics.framework seemed to remove all the clip filters and makes iMovie crash when you open a project that uses a clip filter" Is it always correct?